# How to create a dictionary where the key is the combination of three strings?

Tags: c#

I want to create a dictionary like

```
string, string, string: string
```

Is this possible in C#?

If it is possible, how to access the value by key?

Comment: Read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples

Comment: Value tuple....

Comment: Will I able to use ContainsKey when i use a tuple?

Comment: Test it and find out. However, with string and other primitive  types the answer is yes

Answer (score 3):

`var d = new Dictionary<(string, string, string), string>();` should do the job.

See [Tuple types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples).

Here's an example:

```
var key1 = ("a","b","c");

var d = new Dictionary<(string,string,string),string>()
{
    {key1, "value1"},
    {("a","b","d"), "value2"}
};

Console.WriteLine($"{d.ContainsKey(key1)}");
Console.WriteLine($"{d.ContainsKey(("a","b","x"))}");
```

This produces:

```
True
False
```

#### Option B. Make your own key

Depending on your needs and details of your keys the following pair could work too:

- `Dictionary<string,string>` plus
- `public static string GetKey(string a, string b, string c) => a+b+c;`

This way `"aa" + "b" + "c"` == `"a" + "ab" + "c"` but this may be OK or you could use a separator. You know your data, so you can make the best choice.